# How to find the kth smallest element of a list without sorting the list?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, cuda

I need to find the median of an array without sorting or copying the array.

The array is stored in the shared memory of a cuda program. Copying it to global memory would slow the program down and there is not enough space in shared memory to make an additional copy of it there.

I could use two 'for' loops and iterate over every possible value and count how many values are smaller than it but this would be O(n^2). Not ideal

Does anybody now of a O(n) or O(nlogn) algorithm which solves my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)?

Comment: Refer this:http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/to-find-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array

Comment: @higuaro I'm not sure how to implement QuickSelect without sorting the array. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @user403348255 That question doesn't actually address not being able to sort the array.

Comment: @Gottfried QuickSelect won't necessarily sort your array, it'd just reorder the data around the chosen pivot during the search. The algorithm does not require a sorted array as input

Comment: My bad, I am aware of an algo in c++ which does what you require using max/minheap. The same is achieved in java using priority queue.check out this link, this will be surely more helpful : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91764/find-the-kth-largest-element-of-an-array

Comment: Looks like a quick sort variation in which you keep choosing the pivot untill you choose the pivot as the position k . You can have a nice average time ! There are many other ways too !

Comment: Since shared memory can only be accessed by a single block of CUDA threads, I assume that your question is very CUDA-related.
Do you need an algorithm to be performed by a single CUDA thread, or by a whole block of threads? Is there are constraints on N?
If a block of threads are used, then what's the size of block? Perhaps adding number of threads in the time complexity could help to find a solution that is really faster.

Comment: @stgatilov the algorithm would run in a single thread using shared memory which is why the array cannot be sorted or reordered because other threads may also need the information in its original unsorted or reordered state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input are integers with absolute value smaller than C, there's a simple O(n log C) algorithm that needs only constant additional memory: Just binary search for the answer, i.e. find the smallest number x such that x is larger than or equal to at least k elements in the array. It's easily parallelizable too via a parallel prefix scan to do the counting.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by this. What "simple" algorithm are you talking about?  And how are you binary searching **an un sorted** list? And if the list is sorted then why would I need to binary search for the Kth element, when I can just *get* the kth element?

Answer (score 2):

Your time and especially memory constraints make this problem difficult. It becomes easy, however, if you're able to use an approximate median.

Say an element *y* is an *ε approximate median* if

*m/2 − ε m < rank(y) < m/2 + ε m*

Then all you need to do is sample

*t = 7ε<sup>−2</sup>
log(2δ
<sup>−1</sup>
)*

elements, and find their median any way you want.

---

Note that the number of samples you need is *independent of your array's size* - it is just a function of *ε* and *δ*.